# react send image file to api with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following axios call in my app:

```
export const createProduct = (form) => {
  const requestString = inventoryApiString + "products/";
  return axios
    .post(requestString, form, getAuthHeader())
    .then((Response) => {
      return {
        product: Response.data,
        message: null,
      };
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
      let errorMessage = getErrorMessage(Error);
      return errorMessage;
    });
};
```

And this is the content of key `photo` of parameter `form`:
[image]

I am putting the content of the `file` field in the form when the user selects a file, but I get this error from **Django Rest Framework** backend api: `{"photo":["La información enviada no era un archivo. Compruebe el tipo de codificación del formulario."]}`, which means `Information sent is not a file. Check the codification type of the form`.

I don't know what it means.

Comment: Two things immediately come to mind. Where does the variable `form` come from. It should be an instance of `formData`. Also, I'm not familiar with axios, but have you set the content-type to `multi-part/form-data` I know some APIs default to JSON, and will automatically JSON-ify your payload. The File Data would not be send properly in this case.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback from DRF, and show where `form` comes from?

Comment: It was that, @tim-mccurrach, I just made `form` an instance of `formData` and it worked. Thanks a lot